# Why different object share the same array if Ember Object with extend array property

Tags: ember.js

I just don't understand.
I define my own object with extending a array property

```
MyObj = Ember.Object.extend({
  id: 0,
  data: []
});

var obj1 = MyObj.create();
obj1.id = 1;
console.log(obj1.data); # will output []
obj1.data.push("a");

var obj2 = MyObj.create();
obj2.id = 2;
console.log(obj2.data); # will output ["a"]
obj2.data.push("b");

console.log(obj1.data); # will output ["a", "b"]
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/USODEQUH/1/edit)
I thought obj1 and obj2 are totally independent object. Just curious why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that you're setting the `data` property on a prototype which is then shared among objects instantiated from your class.

I explain this in more detail in this post about Ember.Object (see the section on initialization): http://www.cerebris.com/blog/2012/03/06/understanding-ember-object/

Answer (score 1):

To get around this issue you'll want to use the `init` hook to setup the `data` property.

Here's an example JSBin : http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1103/edit

```
MyObj = Ember.Object.extend({
  id: 0,
  data: null,
  init : function(){
    this.set('data',[]);
  }
});

var obj1 = MyObj.create();
obj1.id = 1;
console.log(obj1.get('data')); // will output []
obj1.get('data').pushObject("a");

var obj2 = MyObj.create();
obj2.id = 2;
console.log(obj2.get('data')); // will output []
obj2.get('data').pushObject("b");

console.log(obj1.get('data')); // will output ["a"]
console.log(obj2.get('data')); // will output ["b"]
```